# MySQL how to find the max number of concatenated field of table?

Tags: mysql, max, concatenation

I want to search specific column in a table that has concatenated value, to find the maximum number of concatenation occurred in that column. for any suggestion thanks.

This is my table structure:

**name**    |   **email**

---

johon   |   ab@gmail.com,c.k@n.com,

---

Mike    |  m.new@yahoo.com,l.me@gmail.com,xy@z.com,

---

Now i want to find the max number of concatenation occurred in email column of table.

Comment: First: This is bad DB design. Second: Count the commas

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume that you are trying to count the number of elements in the lists.  This is bad database design.  You should be using a junction table instead.  However, sometimes, we have no control over the design.

Here is a method to do the count:

```
select (length(email) - length(replace(email, ',', '')) as NumEmails
```

I note that the list ends in a comma.  If it didn't, you would need `+ 1`.